# Knockout.js : radio button first click does not show in 3.0, shows in 2.1-2.3

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pr5YQ/7/

I'm having what appears to be a relatively common problem with Knockout.js - whenever a radio button is first selected, the value in the object model updates, but the radio button itself does not show the selection. Upon second selection, the item shows the check.

The interesting thing is that Knockout version 2 works correctly! It's only Knockout version 3 that has an issue. Within the fiddle, switch to any version of Knockout 2 and the form works as needed.

I have checked to see if there are any issues with the data type I'm setting as the value (they're both numbers, which should be fine) and the name/value setup appears to be correct. I would expect that, if I had failed to do either of the above, then the first click failure would show in all versions of Knockout.

Here's a snippet of the data model I have :

```
        "Question_Ref": 1,
            "Question_Text": "Question 1",
            "Response_Ref": -1,
            "Response_Text": "",
            "Selected_Answer_Ref": -1,
            "Answers": [{
            "Answer_Ref": 1,
                "Answer_Text": "Yes",
                "Answer_Fails": false
        }, {
            "Answer_Ref": 2,
                "Answer_Text": "No",
                "Answer_Fails": false
        }]
```

And here's how I take the data object itself and attach the necessary KO bindings :

```
function AttachKOObjectsOnQuestion(question) {
    question.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO = ko.observable(question.Selected_Answer_Ref);
    question.Show_Response_KO = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (!question.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO()) return null;
            if (question.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO() < 0) return null;
            for (selAnswerCount = 0; selAnswerCount < this.Answers.length; selAnswerCount++) {
                var answer = this.Answers[selAnswerCount];
                if (answer.Answer_Ref === this.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO()) {
                    return answer.Answer_Fails;
                }
            }
            return null
        },
        write: function (value) {},
        owner: question
    });
    var answerCount;
    for (answerCount = 0; answerCount < question.Answers.length; answerCount++) {
        AttachKOObjectsOnQuestionAnswer(question, question.Answers[answerCount]);
    }
}

function AttachKOObjectsOnQuestionAnswer(question, answer) {
    answer.ParentQuestion = question;
    answer.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return answer.ParentQuestion.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            var selectedAnswer = parseInt(value, 10);
            answer.ParentQuestion.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO(selectedAnswer);
        },
        owner: answer
    });
}
```

And here's the relevant setup of the radio buttons :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Answers">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { value: Answer_Ref, name: ParentQuestion.Question_Ref }, checked: Selected_Answer_Ref_KO, click: hideValidators" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Answer_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is both my first usage of Knockout and of JSON, so feel free to offer critiques. Thank you!

Comment: I have answered your question, but please, next time you ask a question, try to make a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of providing this block of code (cudos for creating a jsfiddle, though, even in the minimal example case a jsfiddle helps a lot). You'd probably find the issue yourself while creating the minimal example and even if you didn't, there would be a lot less code that anyone who wants to help you needs to read.

Comment: Thank you. I was supposed to remove all of the much of the crap (simply to test if if it was causing the issue) but I'd forgotten. You're not the only person to point this out, and I will need to do better about providing workable examples in the future.

Comment: Simplified code here : [http://jsfiddle.net/pr5YQ/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/pr5YQ/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered [by Adam Rackis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352552/adam-rackis) on Facebook.

Knockout 3 uses strict comparison, and I had not realized that anything in an input value is a string. As a result, the radio button value (a string) never matched my data model's value (a number).

Worse, I missed that the documentation mentions that you can use the checkedValue binding to set values that are not strings. That is the correct fix for my problem, as I want my data model's current type to remain a number.

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: ParentQuestion.Question_Ref }, checkedValue : Answer_Ref, checked: Selected_Answer_Ref_KO, click: hideValidators" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your `checked` binding is incorrect on the radiobutton. You're trying to bind `checked` to a property on your answer called `Selected_Answer_Ref_KO`. However, that you have added that object to the Question, not the Answer.

To fix this problem, just change your `checked` binding to `checked: $parent.Selected_Answer_Ref_KO`. I have updated your fiddle with this change and the selection work on the first click for me. You can find that update at http://jsfiddle.net/pr5YQ/5/.

Comment: There is actually a KO computed function on the answer with the same name. If you go back to the initial version, you'll see that there is a response that should show/hide in certain cases, and the fact that this isn't working is probably a sign that the value isn't being set.

That said, I should start using $parent, rather than explicitly adding the parent object myself. It seems that every property I set slows the page rendering down, so anything I can remove, I should.

Comment: Added $parent and simplified even more at [http://jsfiddle.net/pr5YQ/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/pr5YQ/9/). Alerts show that the data model's being updated as before.